# ts1206 decorators are not valid here, Angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular

I started to program Angular 2 and I stuck with an error:

> ts1206 decorators are not valid here

```
@Component({   //  ts1206 decorators are not valid here
  selector: 'my-app',
  moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css']
})
```

**Update:**

My tsconfig.json:

```
 {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  }
}
```

what can I do with it?

Comment: the `@Component()` has to be directly before a class, do you have an exported class just below that decorator?

Comment: what is in your `tsconfig.json` ?

Comment: Refer quick-start article - https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html

Comment: @JarodMoser   Okay thanks,this was the problem. Please write it as an answer so I can approve it.

Comment: I added some code between the two and that generated the error. Once removed as per the suggestions that error disappeared

Answer (score 164, accepted):

The Decorators must come directly before an exported class for example:

```
@Component({
    ...
})
export class someComponent{}
```

this goes the same for `@Pipe` `@Directive` `@Injectable` and `@NgModule`

Comment: Order matters.  I had an export interface right after my Injectable and got this error.  Moving export class up to immediately after the Injectable and the interface after that resolved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

This error came to me when I used angular routing and defined routes after `@NgModule` decorator.

We need to define routes or any other decorater before the `@NgModule` decorator.

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [    // define this before @NgModule 
 { path: '',
   redirectTo: '/home',
   pathMatch: 'full'
 },
 { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
];


@NgModule({            // This Decorator should be just before an exported class 
declarations: [
 AppComponent,
 HeaderComponent,
 HomeComponent
],
imports: [
 BrowserModule,
 RouterModule.forRoot(
   appRoutes,
   { enableTracing: true } // <-- debugging purposes only
 )
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score -1):

Add an interface or other declaration above `@component`. This will fix the error.