# ts1206 decorators are not valid here, Angular 6 Tutorial Example

Tags: angular

The "decorator" in question appears in the following block.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MyNavComponent,
    FirstPageComponent,
    SecondPageComponent,
    ThirdPageComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    LayoutModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    MatIconModule,
    MatListModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

The example is my understanding of the way to import the **RouterModule** into the application described in the tutorial, [Angular Material And Angular 6 – Material Design For Angular](https://codingthesmartway.com/angular-material-and-angular-6-material-design-for-angular/).

The messages generated by the trsnspiler, running in my local development server, follow.

> Date: 2018-06-03T19:57:21.828Z - Hash: 46428b505e290e79e66d - Time:
>   632ms 4 unchanged chunks chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 15.3
>   kB [initial] [rendered] i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully. ERROR in
>   src/app/app.module.ts(14,1): error TS1206: Decorators are not valid
>   here.

I posted the whole application, minus the node_modules directory, is in [StringMorph_20180603_151629.zip](https://p6lists-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/p/dagray/EWKACxnmbyJGv3Qi3kDKQfcBqwI5b33y2SbALKGznFKG1w?e=Srmr1l), on my OneDrive.

What nuance, obvious to all but me, did I overlook?

Comment: in my case, i would have declaration export interface between @Component and export class MyClass, and i moved my declartion export interface later of imports.

Answer (score 5):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38358485/2266428) appears to be correct.  The export class statement must immediately follow any decorator such as @Injectable, @NgModule, etc.  The last two lines of your block above should be:

```
})
export class ModuleName { }
```